# Query regarding getting input from user in C

Tags: c

Here I am referring to a question from "codechef.com". Here this below code is used to read the initial count from the user. This will return an integer value.

This is similar to doing a `scanf("%d", &n);`. But most people are using this type of method to get the information from the user.

I do not understand one line in this code, and I do not understand where the character input gets converted to an integer.

```
int readuint()
{
int n = 0;
char c = fgetc(stdin);
do {
n = n * 10 + (c - '0');
} while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n');
return n;
}
```

The item in question is this line - `n = n * 10 + (c - '0');` What is this line doing ??

For full code visit : http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/1221364

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the input is `123`, then on each iteration of the loop, it calculates:

```
n =  0 * 10 + ('1' - '0');
n =  1 * 10 + ('2' - '0');
n = 12 * 10 + ('3' - '0');
assert(n == 123);
```

The character codes for the digits are always consecutive, so `'1' - '0'` is 1, etc.

It converts the digits of a number into a number.  Get used to the idiom; you will see it a lot in C code.

---

The code shown is sloppy in a variety of ways:

```
int readuint()
{
    int n = 0;
    char c = fgetc(stdin);
    do {
        n = n * 10 + (c - '0');
    } while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n');
    return n;
}
```

The name indicates it is reading an unsigned integer (`uint`), but the type used is a signed `int`.  The type of `c` should be `int` because `fgetc()` (and `getc()` and `getchar()`) return an `int` and not a `char`.  There's no way to indicate that it encountered EOF.  There's no protection against overflow.  There's no protection against non-digits in the input.  Fixing all those requires quite a lot of code, but basic self-protection for the code means it should be more like:

```
int readint(void)
{
    int n = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(stdin) != EOF && isdigit(c))
        n = n * 10 + (c - '0');
    if (c != EOF && c != '\n')
        ungetc(fp, c);
    return n;
}
```

There's still no protection against overflow, but it has rudimentary protection against EOF and non-digits in the input (leaving characters other than a newline or EOF to be reprocessed by putting it back for the next read operation).

---

> `'1'-'0' (char) = (int)1`? How does this conversion happen? From `char` to `int`: is it because we are assigning to an integer container — i.e `int n`?

As [Elchonon Edelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2171689/elchonon-edelson) said, the character constants such as `'0'` and '`1`' are integer constants in C (they'd be `char` constants in C++), and the values for `'0'` and `'1'` are very often 48 and 49 respectively (but the C standard does not guarantee that!).  So, `49 - 48` gives `1`, of course.

Comment: '1'-'0' (char) = (int)1 ??? how this conversion is happening ?? from char to int. is it because we are assigning to an integer container ? i.e int n ??

Comment: The character constants  (such as `'0'`) actually have `int` type in C. Additionally, if you assign a value from a smaller-sized integer to a variable of a larger integer type, the value is promoted automatically. It doesn't require effort to convert a `1` that is of `char` type or `short` type to a `1` of `int` type or `long` type...

Comment: Would not `scanf()` functionality also `ungetc('\n')`?  BTW: I believe it is OK to ungetc(EOF) C11 7.21.7.10.4 "If the value of c equals that of the macro EOF, the operation fails and the input stream is unchanged."  Thus recommend dropping the `if (c != EOF && c != '\n')`.

Comment: Further simplification idea: change to `while (isdigit(c = fgetc(stdin)))`.  `isdigit(EOF)` returns 0.

Comment: @chux: I thought about that when writing the code and decided I didn't like it and wouldn't write it like that.  You're correct; it could be done.  However, I don't feel that it is good style, for all it is correct.

Comment: @chux: Addressing your `scanf()` question: yes, `scanf()` would effectively `ungetc('\n')` or whatever other character terminated the number. However, I was simulating the code in the `readuint()` function in the question, which reads up to and including a newline (going into an infinite loop if it gets EOF before the newline). So, my replacement function reads the newline, leaving the input at the start of the next line in the normal case where there is a simple number on the line of input. Since `ungetc(EOF)` fails, I don't do it, but as before, you're probably correct and it could be done.